# CvLoadImage function and lists

Tags: c, list, opencv, path

I am using CvLoadImage (in C programming language).

Instead of passing the path or the name of my, let's say, `.jpg` file as the argument of the function, can I use a list (dynamic structure) which has every path of every `.jpg` image I want to open?

For example, I have thought the code to be like this:

`CvLoadImage(list->name)`

having a list declared with all the paths of the names.

instead of being like this: `CvLoadImage("name.jpg")`

In every manual I read, it just specified the function receives the name or the path of **one** image, but I want to recursively open one image after the other with those paths coming from a list, and I don't know how to do it.

This is what I could do (some things are in spanish, because we speak spanish, and some other things are mixed with files)

```
struct fotos
{
  char nom[30];
  struct fotos *sig;
};
//....
struct fotos *lini;
//....

while(lini->sig!=0)
  {
    image=cvLoadImage(lini->nom,1);
    cvNamedWindow("ejemplo", 0);
    cvMoveWindow("ejemplo", 100, 100);
    cvShowImage("ejemplo", image);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    lini=lini->sig;
  }
  image=cvLoadImage(lini->nom,1);
  cvNamedWindow("ejemplo", 0);
  cvMoveWindow("ejemplo", 100, 100);
  cvShowImage("ejemplo", image);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&image);
```

But it won't work either. It creates a new window, but no image is loaded.

Comment: You will need to loop through the list by yourself and simply call cvLoadImage for any item.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used CvLoadImage() myself, but a quick google search shows that it has a prototype of the form:

```
IplImage* cvLoadImage( const char* filename, int iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
```

The function is clearly designed to take one, and only one filename. It loads the file into memory and returns a pointer to the location into which it loaded it, or NULL for error.

If you want to load multiple files, you'll need to call the function repeatedly, one for each file. One thing you might consider is to set up an array of pointers to char:

```
void load_images(void)
{
    int i;  /* Used for looping */

    /* Array of filenames */
    char *filenames[4] = {
        "/path/to/image0.jpg",
        "/path/to/image1.jpg",
        "/path/to/image2.jpg",
        "/path/to/image3.jpg",
    };

    /* Array to store the addresses of the loaded files */
    IplImage *file_addresses[4];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        file_addresses[i] = cvLoadImage(filenames[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);        
    }

    /* The address of image number N, where N starts at zero
       is now in file_addresses[N]. Don't forget to check that
       any given address is not NULL before you use it, in case
       there was a loading error */
}
```

You can easily substitute the arrays for a linked list or any other data structure you like. You can also modify the function to receive a pointer to a list to populate, or return a pointer to a new list it created, etc.

Comment: This is what I could do (some things are in spanish, because we speak spanish, and some other things are mixed with files)

struct fotos
{
  char nom[30];
  struct fotos *sig;
};
//....
struct fotos *lini;
//....

while(lini->sig!=0)
  {
    image=cvLoadImage(lini->nom,1);
    cvNamedWindow("ejemplo", 0);
    cvMoveWindow("ejemplo", 100, 100);
    cvShowImage("ejemplo", image);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    lini=lini->sig;
  }
  image=cvLoadImage(lini->nom,1);
  cvNamedWindow("ejemplo", 0);
  cvMoveWindow("ejemplo", 100, 100);
  cvShowImage("ejemplo", image);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&image);

Answer (score 0):

What you basically have should be of the form

```
class list
{
    element* begin;
} MyList;

class element
{
    char name[200];
    element* next;
};

//    and you can iterate through the list like that:

    for (element* it = MyList->begin; it != NULL; it = it->next)
    {
         IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(it->name);
         doSomethingElseOn(img);
    }
```